# Spring config location file not found exception

Tags: spring, spring-security

In my web app i'm trying to use spring security. I have the following project structure:

[image: Project structure]

In my web.xml i set the configLocations like this:

[image: Project structure]

And in my HibernateUtil, i create the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext like this:

[image: Project structure]

But, when i execute the app, i get the following errors:

```
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML    document from class path resource [resources/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is    java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/applicationContext.xml] cannot     be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:441)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
... 20 more
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that you have the file packaged into your WAR?
If it is not on the classpath you will get errors.
You may need to play around with the maven war plugin's build settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See maven war plugin.

Check your target folder actually contains the files.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html

Comment: I added the <resource> tag to the pom.xml and that solved the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that would be the cause, but I wanted to point you to the documentation. Better this way if you can find it yourself next time :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly telling you that it cannot find resources/applicationContext.xml in your classpath.

Looking at your code organization, I think the problem is that your Spring applicaitonContext.xml file is directly under WEB-INF and in a typical web-application, this is **NOT** in the classpath. You would be better off creating a WEB-INF/classes/ folder and putting your applicationContext.xml file in there.

Since the error is complaining about resources/appliationContext.xml you may also need to create a WEB-INF/classes/resources/ folder and put it in there.

Comment: I considered down voting this due to the tone of this answer. Telling someone that the response is 'clearly' visible is condescending. If it was clear to them, they would not ask for help.